# Loading image of explosion when collision with character sprite in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am using the verbatim code from a tutorial to trigger an explosion when a projectile collides with a Trump sprite. I have pasted below the explosion class, the section of code where the images for the explosion are loaded, and the code where I do the collision in the update section.  I am getting the following error self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0] NameError: name 'explosion_anim' is not defined.  I started to think it was because I define explosion_anim later in the code but the guy in the tutorial has his code like mine. If someone could please help.

```
class Explosion(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center, size):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 50

    def update(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == len(explosion_anim[self.size]):
                self.kill()
            else:
                center = self.rect.center
                self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
```

## I forgot to note that this stuff is under load_images. It might have not been the best place to put it.

```
def load_images
        #other images loaded here
        explosion_anim = {}
        explosion_anim['lg'] = []
        explosion_anim['sm'] = []
        for i in range(9):
            filename = 'regularExplosion0{}.png'.format(i)
            img = pg.image.load(filename).convert()
            img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
            img_lg = pg.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
            explosion_anim['lg'].append(img_lg)
            img_sm = pg.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
            explosion_anim['sm'].append(img_sm)
```

The section for the code where the collision is performed is below.

```
 def update:
       TrumpHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.trump, self.projectiles, True)
        for hit in TrumpHits:
            print("TRUMP HIT!!!")
            expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'lg')
            all_sprites.add(expl)
```

Comment: `explosion_anim` is a local variable in `update` but you're accessing it in `__init__`. You're also accessing it in `update` before it was assigned.

Comment: Either the guy in the tutorial doesn't know what he's doing, or you copied something wrong. The code clearly messed with the namespaces. explosion_anim in `__init__` is searching in the global namespace while explosion_anim is defined in `update`

Comment: I copied and pasted        explosion_anim = {} , explosion_anim['lg'] = [] and
        explosion_anim['sm'] = [] into my class definition now I am getting an error saying the index of        self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0] is out of range. THanks for the comments.

Comment: As hilarious as @JacobG. 's comment is and knowing that it'll become meaningless, I *really* think this question deserves a better title. I'll suggest an edit but really virtually anything would make it more likely to help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load the images globally. (I've put them into a directory with the name 'Explosions'.)

```
EXPLOSION_IMGS = [pg.image.load(os.path.join('Explosions', img)).convert_alpha()
                  for img in os.listdir('Explosions')]
```

Then reduce the Explosions class to this version. It accesses the global constant `EXPLOSION_IMGS` list and then just increments the frame counter in its `update` method, after the required time has passed.

```
class Explosion(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = EXPLOSION_IMGS[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=center)
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 50

    def update(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
        if self.frame == len(EXPLOSION_IMGS):
            self.kill()
        else:
            self.image = EXPLOSION_IMGS[self.frame]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
```

In the `update` method of the game class, create the `expl` instance and add it to the `self.all_sprites` group. Done.

```
class Game:

    def update(self):
        # ...
        TrumpHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.trump, self.projectiles, True)
        for hit in TrumpHits:
            print("TRUMP HIT!!!")
            expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center)
            self.all_sprites.add(expl)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0]
```

This is where the error lies. The error is thrown because you are referencing the dictionary `explosion_anim` when the object is initialized (that is, within the `__init()__` method) but the dictionary doesn't even exist until you create it in `the update()` method.

Instead of `self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0]` try:

```
img = pg.image.load('regularExplosion00.png').convert()
img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
if size == 'lg':
    self.image = pg.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
elif size == 'sm':
    self.image = pg.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))
```

---

Explicitly, this should be your new `__init()__`:

```
def __init__(self, center, size):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.size = size

    img = pg.image.load('regularExplosion00.png').convert()
    img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    if size == 'lg':
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
    elif size == 'sm':
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(img, (32, 32))

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = center
    self.frame = 0
    self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()
    self.frame_rate = 50
```

Comment: You are saying add the to the class definition correct?

Comment: Yes, specifically in the `__init()__` method. Replace this with my 5 lines of code from above:  `self.image = explosion_anim[self.size][0]`

Comment: Still get    print("explosion index", explosion_anim[self.size][0])
NameError: name 'explosion_anim' is not defined .

Comment: And now when adding explosion_anim[] etc. I get index out of range again. Do i need to move the code around?

Comment: I am getting the beginning of an explosion. But there is now an error saying:    if self.frame == len(explosion_anim[self.size]):
NameError: name 'explosion_anim' is not defined

Comment: Add this as a final line to your `load_images()` and make sure it has only 4 spaces in front of it, not 8: `return explosion_anim` This is critical - without this, you load the images in but then drop them on the ground instead of handing them off to the rest of your code. Then you need to alter your `update()` method to call these images in so that it knows what you mean when you say `if self.frame == len(explosion_anim[self.size]):` because you haven't told that function what `explosion_anim` is. (continued in next comment)

Comment: On the line before that `if` statement, put `explosion_anim = load_images()` which will create the variable explosion_anim and fill it with the images that your other function will supply when it returns them.

Comment: You mean before the if statement you told me to past e in?

Comment: No, before `if self.frame == len(explosion_anim[self.size]):`

Comment: I get load_images not defined now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is load_images a part of your class definition, or is it a function that's not part of the class?

Comment: Its just the definition where I put the loaded image part of the code. There is a number of loaded images. That placement mgiht have been bad on my half but it was left open where they should go.

Comment: Try `explosion_anim = self.load_images()` instead of `explosion_anim = load_images()`. If you defined load_images as a method of the class, this will work.

Comment: load images is not a definition under the Explosion class. I might have screwed up there. Load_images() is under the Trump class. Should I move that part of my code somewhere else?

Comment: Its saying Explosion has nothing called load_images. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a definition for the class Explosion to place my images. Should have known. Update. I am only displaying one of the images of the 9. I have made all the above changes but apparently it doesn't loop through.

Comment: I have a feeling that not all the images (9 in total are being displayed) sometime it doesnt work as well.